# Bootstrap tabs don't switch property when trying to move between tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Like you see the below code snippet, I mixed up `owl-carousel` and `Bootstrap's tabs` so that I can make a sliding tabs. Everything is working well. But, the problem is explained with the below images.

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme nav nav-pills nav-pills-primary rank-carousel" role="tablist">

  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#boutique"role="tablist" aria-expanded="true">
      Boutique
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#streetwear"role="tablist" aria-expanded="true">
      Streetwear
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#designer"role="tablist" aria-expanded="true">
      Designer
    </a>
  </li>

  ...

</div>
```

This is the initial state of the sliding tabs. Boutique is selected as a default. Orange color means active.

[image]

When I click Streetwear, Boutique's supposed to be inactive, but it just stays active, which means when I try to go back to Boutique, nothing happens.

[image]
So, becase of that, I want to make the previous selected tab inactive when I click another tab. It was supposed to be supported with pure tabs of Bootstrap, but for some reason, it doesn't work after mixing it up with owl-carousel slider.

Does anyone know hwy?

**UPDATE**

[This documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#events) seems related to what I want to do. So, based on that, I tried the following.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on("hide.bs.tab", function(e) {
  console.log("hide.bs.tab");
});
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on("hidden.bs.tab", function(e) {
  console.log("hidden.bs.tab");
});
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on("show.bs.tab", function(e) {
  console.log(show.bs.tab);
});
```

It just console logged "show.bs.tab" even though there was a active tab already. The documentation says that `hide.bs.tab` and `hidden.bs.tab` are supposed to be called if there are previously active tabs.

Comment: Can you add the relevant CSS and JS. Maybe recreating the issue in a codepen or jsfiddle would be helpful. its really difficult with just the HTML code provided.

Comment: I hate to say this, but the relevant CSS and JS are literally Bootstrap and Owl Carousel libraries. I don't think it's efficient to look up the whole library. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#events I found the relevant functions by Bootstrap itself. Updated the original post with the code I tried with the link.

Comment: Shouldn't the first tab be marked with "active" class, as I think BS toggles rather than removes the class from the old and new tabs.